# AWS S3 Lambda event - get, update, then put JSON file from same bucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm modifying the AWS Lambda with Amazon S3 tutorial found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) so that it will simply--

- read a JSON file (the content index) already resident in that bucket,
- update it with the newly created Key (a new "folder" in that bucket that triggered this Lambda),
- and then save (put) the updated JSON file back.

**CLARIFICATION:**
The bucket should only trigger the Lambda function when a folder object is created in it. The content index (index.json) is already resident in the bucket. So, bucket will have folders (e.g., {folder-1, folder-2, folder-n}) and index.json. Every time a new folder is added, it's added to the JSON array.

To be specific, in my case I have a root (destination) bucket that will have a series of folders created by Elemental MediaConvert. Each folder represents a new video; and within each folder are the different formats that may be served to different devices. Back at the root level I have index.json which is an array of these video folders; it is the content index. Now, I could modify the Lambda that is part of the MediaConvert flow.. but I'll consider that at another time. Here, I just want to trigger a new S3 Lambda every time MediaConvert writes a new video folder... which is just some random GUID thing.

I'm learning Node JS and this is the first time I've used some of the structure and calls you see here. (I'm at least aware that this form is cleaner and clearer than using callbacks.)

Since it's going to be tricky (for me!) to test this as a Lambda function, would someone kindly point me at any obvious mistakes??

Also, would someone provide me some direction on how to test this Lambda function manually using Amazon S3 event data (prior to configuring the actual bucket to publish the required event)? I would think I need the event.json to specify the name of that newly created folder so it can be added to my index.json which is also sitting in the same bucket.

Here's my code:

```
// dependencies
var async = require('async');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var util = require('util');

// constants
//const DEST_FOLDER = 'my-triggering-bucket';
const CONTENT_INDEX_FILENAME = 'index.json';

// get reference to S3 client
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // Read options from the event.
    // Need the new folder (key) that's been added to the bucket...
    console.log("Reading options from event:\n", util.inspect(event, {depth: 5}));

    // I assume this is the triggering bucket...
    var triggerBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;

    // And I assume this is the folder that was added and caused the trigger
    var newKey    = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key);

    const indexKey = CONTENT_INDEX_FILENAME;

    // Get the content index and add the newly created dir to it
    async.waterfall([
        function download(next) {
            // Download the content index from S3 into a buffer.
            s3.getObject({
                    Bucket: triggerBucket,
                    Key: indexKey
                },
                next);
        },
        function update(response, next) {
          // Update the content index with the new dir that was added
          console.log('UPDATE...');
          var obj = JSON.parse(response);
          obj.push(newKey);
          var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(obj);
          next(null, jsonStr.ContentType, jsonStr);
        },
        function upload(contentType, data, next) {
            // Stream the updated content index back
            s3.putObject({
                    Bucket: triggerBucket,
                    Key: indexKey,
                    Body: data,
                    ContentType: contentType
                },
                next);
            }
        ], function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('error: ' + err);
            } else {
                console.log('Success);
            }

            callback(null, "message");
        }
    );
};
```

**UPDATE**
I've abandoned this approach in favor of updating the content index via another means that does not risk runaway execution of my Lambda. I have discovered first-hand that it is not a good idea to try to trigger a specific createObject event in a bucket when one's design does not provide a solid event notification filter. (I could not filter on a suffix of a simple `/`.) Also, I was expecting a single folder key object create event to trigger my Lambda, but in reality other folders and keys created *inside* that new root level folder ended up triggering my Lambda too. So, this sent me into the video conversion workflow to modify the Lambda that notifies the successful completion of the workflow such that it updates my content index.

Comment: Heads up #1: it will be safer to use two buckets, otherwise if this Lambda function is writing to the same bucket that triggered it, and the new or overwritten object (created by the Lambda function) also triggers the Lambda function, you have an infinite loop of Lambda invocations and bucket `PUT` actions that can cost real $ if not detected promptly.  Ensure, at minimum, that the new object will not trigger inclusion of itself.

Comment: Heads up #2: this code will misplace (occasionally omit) files for inclusion in the index because there's an implicit assumption that the Lambda function won't run concurrently when parallel uploads occur - which it will - and that s3.getObject always gets the most recent copy of the (index) object that has been overwritten - which it may not.  That is not guaranteed.  An overwrite followed quickly by a read may return the old or the new object.  It will always return an intact object, but S3 only guarantees eventual consistency for overwrites.

Comment: Thanks for those heads ups. NO, I hadn't considered either case.. but I like to think that the first one would have dawned on me as I got close! It would be easy enough to prevent because the trigger action would be a new "folder" appearing in the bucket.. not the updated JSON object. I need to think about @athar-kahn 's reply below bc he seems to indicate a new folder create won't trigger my Lambda. As for point 2, at this stage there can be no possibility of concurrency.. but it's def something to keep in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Lambda will only be triggered when a new object is created/deleted/modified in the bucket depending on your configuration. If you create a new folder in the bucket it won't trigger your Lambda. You can simplify your code by using async/await syntax in Lambda Node.js 8.1 runtime.

**Lambda handler**

```
var AWSS3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');
const CONTENT_INDEX_FILENAME = 'index.json';
var s3 = new AWSS3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {

  try {
    console.log('Event', JSON.stringify(event));

    // Bucket name.
    const triggerBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;

    // New key added.
    const newKey = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;

    // Assuming only folder name is to be added in the list. If object 
    // is added in the bucket root then it will be ignored.
    if (newKey.indexOf('/') > -1) {

      // Get existing data.
      let existing = await s3.getObject({
        Bucket: triggerBucket,
        Key: CONTENT_INDEX_FILENAME
      }).promise();

      // Parse JSON object.
      let existingData = JSON.parse(existing.Body);

      // Get the folder name.
      const folderName = newKey.substring(0, newKey.indexOf("/"));

      // Check if we have an array.
      if (!Array.isArray(existingData)) {
        // Create array.
        existingData = [];
      }

      existingData.push(folderName);

      await s3.putObject({
        Bucket: triggerBucket,
        Key: CONTENT_INDEX_FILENAME,
        Body: JSON.stringify(existingData),
        ContentType: 'application/json'
      }).promise();

      console.log(`Added new folder name ${folderName}`);

      return folderName;

     } else {
         console.log('Key was added in bucket root.');
         return 'Ignored';
     }
    };
  }
  catch(err) {
    return err;
  }
```

**Running locally:**

Create an event.json file in the root of your project. Add following in the event.json.

```
{
  "Records":[
    {
      "s3":{
        "bucket":{
        "name": "your_bucket_name"
    },
    "object":{
      "key": "your_folder/your_file.json"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Download lambda local package globally.

`npm install -g lambda-local`

Finally test it:

Run function locally by passing the event.json file created above.

`lambda-local -l path/to/function.js -e event.json`

Comment: *"If you create a new folder in the bucket it won't trigger your Lambda."* Depending on terminology, that isn't true.  Creating a folder using the console creates a zero-byte object whose name ends with `/` and will trigger any matching event.

Comment: I think the event.json may not be correct, even though I think your Lambda matches my use case perfectly. Nonetheless, thanks so much for making it clear to me how to test. Unless I'm mistaken, the `event.json` must specify the bucket and the _new folder_ (not a json file). The content index that I want to update (i.e., `index.json`) resides directly in the bucket. So, I think the "object" needs to be just "your_folder"... the thing that triggered the event in the first place. Am I right?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you are absolutely right. As OP didn't clarify where S3 triggers are set so I attempted to make it clear that don't expect Lambda trigger by just creating a new folder.

Comment: @motivus event.json looks correct to me. s3.bucket.name is the name of your bucket and s3.object.key is the path of the object being uploaded. If the object is upload in the bucket root then the path would be `filename.json` if it is uploaded in a folder then the path would be `folder_name/file_name.json`

Comment: Also, as @michael-sqlbot pointed out, creating a folder will trigger your Lambda depending on your config so you need to ensure that your `index.json` is not set for trigger otherwise it will end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks @athar-khan. I might not have explained clearly that the bucket should only trigger the Lambda function when a folder object is created in it. I would think I need the event.json to specify the name of that new folder so it can be added to my index.json which is also sitting in the same bucket. With that in mind, does your event.json still suit my use case?

Comment: @motivus so lets say you have a folder "my_json" and here you are adding files. You've also added "my_json" prefix in event notifications for "All object create event" in your bucket. Assuming your index.json file is in the bucket root. index.json contains an array of file names being upload in "my_json" folder. In that scenario, you will need to change the event.json s3.object.key = 'my_json/file_name.json'. Also, you can remove the condition for checking '/' in the key.

Comment: To be specific, in my case I have a root (destination) bucket that will have a series of folders created by Elemental MediaConvert. Each folder represents a new video; and within each folder are the different formats that may be served to different devices. Back at the root level I have index.json which is an array of these video folders; it is the content index. Now, I could modify the Lambda that is part of the MediaConvert flow.. but I'll consider that at another time. Here, I just want to trigger a new S3 Lambda every time MediaConvert writes a new video folder. Does that make sense?

Comment: In that case my code example appears to be the perfect solution. You don't need to worry about event.json that's only for you to test lambda locally. You must ensure that you have a folder (that should also be the prefix for event notification in your bucket) where all other folders are created by MediaConvert. This will ensure that updating index.json will not trigger another Lambda.

Comment: I agree. But.. even though easy, I'd prefer not to modify the MediaConvert Lambda such that it stores the video folders within a folder at the root level. I was hoping that an S3:ObjectCreated event would only be valid for creates (and not updates). In looking at this link...  [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html?shortFooter=true#notification-how-to-filtering] I was hoping I'd see a way to disallow the index.json PUT from being a trigger. Since the folders MediaConvert creates are random GUID things, can I specify a prefix of '/' to recognize it as a folder??

Comment: @motivus you can use the code I’ve attached in my answer to get the folder name from object key. If you think my answer/comments have helped you then please accept it.

Comment: It has helped greatly. Thank you. Answer accepted as most helpful!! :)

Comment: Just a note that the `lambda-local` function option should be `-f` (not `-l`). Also, catch() statement is out of place due to extra }, I believe.

Comment: @athar-khan, I finally tested this on AWS. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It results in runaway execution, which I had to stop by deleting the S3 event notification. I tried to filter the S3 event by only triggering when the suffix was `/`... but the Lambda was never triggered when the video folder was created. When I removed that filter, the function was called repeatedly, every time `index.json` was written back. It just kept adding the same folder name over and over again. I stopped it after about 50 executions, so nothing crazy.

Comment: I'm trying to decipher the logs for this Lambda function now. One detail I did not mention is that the newly created video folder has folders itself. I don't think this matters because the trigger is on creation events in the root bucket itself... not another level down. Unless I don't understand how S3 createObject events.

Answer (score 0):

As for testing locally, I've previously used https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-lambda-local and it has worked fine for me.

Just check up with the AWS docs for example S3 event json data

Comment: Thanks Andy. I will install that package!

Comment: I see that this resource will help me to resolve the errors I'm encountering when trying to install aws-lambda-local globally... https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally